# Ctrl + D not raising EOFError in Vs Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, error-handling, terminal

Every time in my terminal when I press ctrl +D is shows ^d but does not raise the exception I need. Instead is just keeps asking for more input and does not end the program.
Any fixes for this

```
groceryList = {}
while True:
    try:
        item = input()
        if item not in groceryList:
            groceryList[item] = 1
        else:
            groceryList[item] = groceryList[item] + 1

    except EOFError:
        for key in groceryList:
            print(key)
            
        break
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: This is a terminal configuration issue, not a Python code issue. `input` raises `EOFError` when the underlying read from standard input signals an end of file. That doesn't happen if your terminal doesn't "close" standard input in response to the key combination.

Comment: So how do I configure my terminal to accept it

Comment: @Big_Port: We have no idea what is "my terminal". So nobody can answer, but possibly it is off-topic here (how to use programs). In any case, in Windows many programs (also Python) do not use Control-D for end-of-file (and it may not be possible to simulate it, depending the operating system). (C++ inventor recommends to use a keyword on Windows, as "QUIT", and Control-D on the rest). (or just use an empty line as "quit"

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer, to get eoferror in windows it's CNTRL+Z not D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).